# Standard training and test corpuses for POS tagging

Tags: natural-language-processing

I'm wondering if there is a standard corpus that people use to evaluate their part-of-speech taggers.  I am implementing my own tagger, and would like a meaningful way to measure its performance, which would ideally be against the same corpuses that other people are using.

Comment: Have you tried doing a literature search to look for published papers on part-of-speech tagging, and see what they did in their evaluation section?

Comment: @D.W. A lot of the information I could find was about the tag sets people used, but not about training texts.

Comment: This is not exactly what you are looking for, but may be helpful nevertheless: http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/batch.html the list of all sentences properly parsed by link-grammar's parser. You could also ask on their mailing list for the corpus they use for testing (afaik it was archives of some American periodic).